# Brackets - unable to edit defaultPreferences.json file (trying to set linting to jshint but not jslint)

Tags: adobe-brackets

I am running Brackets on a macbook pro and when I press cmd+, and try to edit the defaultPreferences.json file, it does not allow me to make any changes to the file (nothing happens when I type). If I restart Brackets I can edit the file, but after closing and re-opening the preferences file, the changes are reverted.

I have tried editing the json file with TextEdit while Brackets is closed, but Brackets still likes to reverse the changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had similar issue , and i did open [issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/12108) at [Bracket's GitHub repository](https://github.com/adobe/brackets) and here is the solution from its developers:-

> `defaultPreferences.json` is a read-only file: take the options you
>   want to modify and copy them to the `brackets.json` file on the other
>   pane. This will override the defaults. You will also see code hints
>   while typing the values in to `brackets.json` which will help picking
>   the correct options.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is also available to install **brackets-preferences plugin** and edit from there. Once installed go to View -> Preferences in your Brackets interface to edit preferences.